# Modificar configuração de carrosel em bootstrap 4

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estou utilizando o modelo abaixo para fazer um slide, modelo no qual peguei de uma pergunta anterior que fiz e uma pessoa me ajudou colando o caminho, porém o slide esta grande demais e preciso diminuir o tamanho ou seja o height, porém não estou encontrando no bootstrap a folha de stylo css que contenha o elemento .carousel-inner para fazer as modificações.

```css
.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=777&amp;fg=555&amp;text=First slide" alt="First slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_162016ba554%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_162016ba554%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
        data-holder-rendered="true">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=666&amp;fg=444&amp;text=Second slide" alt="Second slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_162016ba556%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_162016ba556%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3203125%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
        data-holder-rendered="true">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=555&amp;fg=333&amp;text=Third slide" alt="Third slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_162016ba557%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_162016ba557%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22277%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
        data-holder-rendered="true">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sol se precisar de ajuda com o Slide do outro site posta a pergunta aqui que eu tento te ajudar. Boa sorte com o projeto. E não deixe de estudar os códigos das respostas para entender o que está sendo feito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu fiz esse modelo que vc pode controlar a altura do slider, no exemplo coloquei com 30% da altura da tela.

Veja na parte do CSS que eu deixei comentado como ajustar.

```css
.carousel-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh; /* aqui vc ajusta a altura do slider */
}
.carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;
    /* transform: translateY(-50%)  habilitar se quiser pocicionar o meio da imagem no slider*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=
 content=
>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

</head>
<body>

        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=777&amp;fg=555&amp;text=First slide" alt="First slide [800x400]" src="http://placecage.com/800/400" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h3>First slide label</h3>
                      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=666&amp;fg=444&amp;text=Second slide" alt="Second slide [800x400]" src="http://fillmurray.com/800/400" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=555&amp;fg=333&amp;text=Third slide" alt="Third slide [800x400]" src="http://placecage.com/820/400" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada deu certo um dos sites com esse exemplo, agora tem outro site que utiliza outro tipo de slide, valeu.